# How to use System V IPC message queues on Windows Linux subsystem in C?

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a method to use Unix System V IPC message queues on Windows without using pipes?
System V shared memory and semaphore work, but messages do not seem to work on Windows.

Comment: System V is a unix thing.

Comment: Are you using `WSL2` to boot linux under the VM? If so, you can use SysV IPC `msgsnd/msgrcv`. Otherwise you can look at `cygwin` source to see what it does to implement SysV IPC natively.

Comment: Can you give an example of what “seems to not work” ?

Comment: Cygwin offers this (note that MSYS2 does not -- the code will compile but MSYS2 doesn't implement the back end and it just fails at runtime)

Comment: Can you confirm with a `wsl -l -v` whether your instance is WSL1 or WSL2?  According to WSL issue [#1443](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1443) this feature was implemented with the release of WSL2.  It's been my experience that a lot of people have WSL2 installed, but their instances are still WSL1.